# How can my userscript run before inline-javascript runs?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I'm developing my first userscript that blocking anti adblock script.
The adblock detector running in the headers tag as inline javascript. I want to block it or at least run before it. I was able to do so in Firefox using `beforescriptexecute` but I didn't find compatible way in chrome.
Any ideas?

Comment: There's no 100% alternative in Chrome, but you can do [what uBlock extra does](https://github.com/gorhill/uBO-Extra/blob/02bf3ed98fe378147c6a4b19bb93448f6990c1f7/contentscript.js#L246-L269): get the page html, strip the script, rewrite the page completely.

Comment: Thanks, I did as they did and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

beforescriptexecute Was removed from standard by w3c and will be removed from FF soon. There will be no replacement or at least it is not planned yet.
[script tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element)